# office 365 business account also sets some policies in windows - where to see what is set

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, office365

Lately our company rolled out office 365 business for all employees. most of us use windows 7 some use linux (perhaps with a windows vm) and some update to windows 10 (we are free to install whatever we want).

I am using windows 10 with a local administrator account.
In case of office 365 our company prohibits the use of one drive and all cloud features - this is disabled by some kind of administrative policy. Also Cortana is not usable (online search is always disabled short afte enabled by me)
Now i noticed "Some settings are managed by your organisation" (i translated from german). So there seem other setting set via my office 365 account?!

Is there a way to see all settings/policies set by the organisation? Is there a way to just use office and keep it away from my windows?

Comment: You could always try to run `gpresult` to see whenever some form of group policy is applied but this would usually also require your machine to be part of a domain. Though they can be directly written to various places as well. For a start, run `gpresult` and have a look.

Comment: i tried it with /R paramater - nothing unusual i would say. You are right i am not member of a domain.

Comment: As they might have directly wrote the keys you probably should rather run `gpresult /H report.html` and view the result. That way you should get a list of Computer and User Configuration settings. I'm not entirely certain it would pickup directly inserted registry settings but it's worth a try. Where did you see the message about the managed features? Wouldn't Office 365 actually be run through your browser?

Comment: I think all what the ops guys did is to set some setting in their office 365 management console. One of those settings was to disable all cloud features (-> no office programs but outllook are available online ). but i am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like your have joined your Windows 10 machine to Azure Active Directory.  When you do this, you will inherit some settings as defined in the Office 365 service.

If they are disabling services, or removing license types from a subscription these can affect your Windows 10 device in relations to these services.  Joining AzureAD sets some basic security controls as well as defined by the Office 365 administrator (like password policy).

Further depending on how it was joined and what other steps have been taken, if you have Intune - they may have more advanced controls you are inheriting.  Windows 10 uses MDM functions (just like your phone) - so no agents need to be installed on the machine for administrators to do this.

You won't be able to get around these on your device without unrolling the device. That process will vary depending on how it's configured and joined in the first place.  Once you leave - you may not be able to access any resources on your machines that are hosted in Office 365 (it's the trade off for access corporate resources).

Comment: thnaks for detailed answer but is there a way to see what is set?

Comment: Go to Settings --> Account --> Access work or school, and under your account setting you should find a link to export management settings. It's an XML file with the settings that get applied.